# Adding timeseries to MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm quit new to MongoDB. Basicaly I have an entity that has some static data and a time series. Due to the time series "problem" I shoose to explore the path of non relational databases. To build a good layout for the database I googled a bit and found [this article](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb), so I tried implementing it and got something link this:

```
 {
   id: 1,
   isActive: true\false,
   sensor: 'some sensor type',
   StatusList: [
         {
            timestap: timestamp
            isSensorWorking: true\false
            sensorValue : double
         }
         {
            timestap: timestamp
            isSensorWorking: true\false
            sensorValue : double
         }
         {
            timestap: timestamp
            isSensorWorking: true\false
            sensorValue : double
         }
         {
            timestap: timestamp
            isSensorWorking: true\false
            sensorValue : double
         }
   ]
}
```

So my first question: Do you guys think this a good implementation?

I'm using MongoDB in java using the Spring Data MongoDB Core library to make the connections between server and client.
What I have in java is 2 classes, one Sensor class and one StatusValue class (time series)

so adding a full sensor to mongo is quit easy, but what is a good implementation to add a new and update a statusValue to an existing satatusList within a Sensor document. So basicaly i'm asking a good implementation to a a time serie to an existing time series?

Comment: Could you describe the use case more? You're not using the standard structure developed in the time series blog post, a structure that has a key for each measurement and no array. Why did you choose that structure? Do your readings come in non-uniformly? You don't get most of the benefits of the time series structure with a big array like `StatusList`.

Comment: I don’t think I got the whole implementation structure design.
so, the case:  a few 1000 embedded devices with some sensor attached should sends their data to a  web service. The backend of the webserver should process the data and store it in a mongodb database. Every time one of the devices sends their data, it’s the battery value, and the value what the sensor measures. So basically a time series. Do you have any reading suggestions?

Comment: There was a very [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385363/mongo-for-non-regular-time-series) not so long ago about timeseries data that's not coming in at uniform intervals, involving sensors, etc. You can use a preallocated document with a fixed # of readings per doc, as opposed to a fixed time interval per doc, or do one reading per document.